# How to pass an array of email adress from cdk context and subscribe to sns topic

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sns

I have 2 email adress which are defined as array In cdk context. How do I subscribe to sns topic.

Here my cdk context

```
"dlqAlertAddress": {
      "alertaddress": [
        "xyz@example.com",
        "abc@example.com"
      ]
    }
```

This is How I am extracting and passing it down to cdk stack.

```
const dlqAlertAddress: {
  alertaddress: string[];
} = app.node.tryGetContext("dlqAlertAddress");
console.log(dlqAlertAddress)


 slackNotificationEbPipe.dlqTopic.addSubscription(
      new subscriptions.EmailSubscription(props.dlqAlertAddress.alertaddress)
    );
```

Error : Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

I dont want to pass it as individual email address and pass 2 values, that is why I am looking for a solution which can help me achieve the same using array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `map` function

```
props.dlqAlerts.mailAddress.map((address, index) => {
    return new sns.Subscription(scope, `${alertAdressMapId}-${index}`, {
      topic: dlqTopic,
      protocol: sns.SubscriptionProtocol.EMAIL,
      endpoint: address,
    });
  });
```